# How to sync and optimize an Oracle Text index?

Tags: oracle, full-text-search, oracle-text

We want to use a `ctxsys.context` index type for full text search. But I was quite surprised, that an index of this type is not automatically updated. We have 3 million documents with about 10k updates/inserts/deletes per day.

What are your recommendations for syncing and optimizing an Oracle Text index?

Comment: what indications do you have that the index is not staying in sync?

Comment: It is quite common for these kinds of tools to not make assumptions about your specific requirements. Creating and maintaining indices on large amounts of unstructured data usually requires some consideration so that your design choices produce a solution with acceptable tradeoffs. The update and maintenance strategies for a search engine will likely be very different from a collaborative authoring solution, which worls appart form supporting analytics. Oracle does give you a small range of sync options to choose from, and with only 10k daily DML you can likely get away with any of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think 'SYNC EVERY' option, as described in previous answer only available in Oracle 10g or newer. If you're using older version of Oracle you would have to run sync operation periodically. For example, you can create following stored procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE 
Procedure sync_ctx_indexes
IS
 CURSOR sql1 is select distinct(pnd_index_owner||'.'||pnd_index_name) as index_name from ctx_pending;
BEGIN
 FOR rec1 IN sql1 LOOP
 ctx_ddl.sync_index(rec1.index_name);
 END LOOP;
END;
```

and then schedule it run via DBMS_JOB:

```
DBMS_JOB.SUBMIT(job_id, 'sync_ctx_indexes;', SYSDATE, 'SYSDATE + 1/720');
```

As for index optimization, following command can be used (also can be scheduled with DBMS_JOB or via cron):

```
alter index my_index rebuild online parameters('optimize full maxtime 60');
```

There is also CTX_* package with similar function available.

Comment: for 11g and up, Oracle does not recommend rebuilding text indices with alter index but  instead use ctxsys.ctx_ddl.optimize_index

Answer (score 17):

What do you mean by "not automatically updated"?

The index can be synchronized on commit or periodically.

```
Create index ... on ... INDEXTYPE IS CTXSYS.CONTEXT PARAMETERS ('SYNC ( ON COMMIT)')
Create index ... on ... INDEXTYPE IS CTXSYS.CONTEXT PARAMETERS 'SYNC (EVERY "SYSDATE+1/24")')
```

I you don't need real-time search accuracy our DBA recommended to sync the index periodically, say each 2 min. If you can afford to do it overnight, then even better. What is best depends on your load and the size of the document.

These links can probably provide you with more information:

- [Oracle TEXT index maintenance](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/text/htdocs/Index_Maintenance.html)
- [Working with Oracle TEXT](http://download.oracle.com/docs/html/A81197_06/oraclete.htm#1019241)

For DBA advice, maybe serverfault is better?

Comment: "On commit" seems not to be recommended. Is it also possible to specify periodical index optimization, on index creation?

Comment: Just a note to keep in mind: If you are using SYNC ( ON COMMIT ) with a MULTI_COLUMN_DATASTORE the index sync will only be triggered when the column containing the actual index is affected. For example if you have a multi-column index over columns A,B and C with the index residing on A, then an UPDATE of column B will NOT trigger the index sync.

Answer (score 4):

Putting this here as an update for Oracle 12C users.
If you use the index in real time mode, then it keeps items in memory, and periodicially pushes to the main tables, which keeps fragmentation down and enables NRT search on streaming content.
Here's how to set it up

```
exec ctx_ddl.drop_preference ( 'your_tablespace' );
exec ctx_ddl.create_preference( 'your_tablespace', 'BASIC_STORAGE' );
exec ctx_ddl.set_attribute ( 'your_tablespace', 'STAGE_ITAB', 'true' );
create index  some_text_idx on your_table(text_col)  indextype is ctxsys.context PARAMETERS ('storage your_tablespace sync (on commit)')
```

this will set up the index in NRT mode. It's pretty sweet.